# AngularJS cookie is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, ionic-framework

**app.js**

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'ngCordova', 'ngCookies'])

.run(function ($ionicPlatform) {
$ionicPlatform.ready(function () {

if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

}
         if (window.StatusBar) {
                StatusBar.styleLightContent();
         }

});
})

.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$stateProvider

  .state('HomePage', {
             url: '/HomePage/:id',
             templateUrl: 'templates/HomePage.html',
             controller: 'HomePageCtrl'
         })
         .state('login', {
             url: '/login',
             templateUrl: 'templates/Login.html',
             controller: 'LoginCtrl'
         });
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

});
```

**controllers.js**

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])



.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, LoginService, $ionicPopup, $state, $location, $http, $cookieStore) {

$cookieStore.put('mycookie', 'cookie value');
var favoriteCookie = $cookieStore.get('mycookie');

alert(favoriteCookie);

})
```

**Question:**

I am new for Angular JS Ionic.I am trying to use **cookie** in angularjs.

When i use **$cookieStore**

I get below **exception**:

**Exception:**

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngCookies due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngCookies' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

I added **ngCookies** to a**ngular.module** however it did not work for me.

Where i miss exactly ? How can i use cookie in angular js.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably you have missed to add [`angular-cookies.js`](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.1/angular-cookies.js) file

If so add it.

Comment: glad to help you :), cheerz

Answer (score 3):

I find that $cookies is not working in an Cordova/Phonegap app since the pages are served as a file URL. In an normal desktop browser it is also not working if you serve the pages from the filesystem - it's working when served via a server or localhost.

So I get to the assumption that angular $cookies don't work for Cordova apps. 
Maybe theres a workaround for that? I just don't know, maybe someone nows an answer.

Comment: I just used AngularJS localStorage, the API is pretty much the same and it's working.

Comment: I have the same issue... It seems like it's not working for Cordova apps (Ionic in my case). I'll check localStorage. Thanks Haba.